# apache2 configuration not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration-files

Now this is likely to be a dumb question as I'm new to Apache and web hosting in general. I'm trying to set configuration options for apache but none of them are working.

The first option I'm trying to set is disabling directory indexes. The directory `/var/www/schedules/` has no `index.html` and I'm trying to get it to display a 403 Forbidden on accessing `/schedules`. I put `Options -Indexes` at the beginning of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but it has no effect. I then tried

```
<Directory />
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

but it also had no effect. I replaced `<Directory />` with `<Directory /var/www/>` but it also had no effect. The only thing that worked was replacing it with `<Directory /var/www/schedules/>`. This doesn't seem to disable directory indexing globally however.

The other thing I'm trying to do is blocking access by IP. However even the simplest things don't work. I added to `apache2.conf` this:

```
<Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

but it didn't work; I could still access all the pages. Tried `<Directory /var/www>`, also didn't work.

Using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory ~ "/var/www/.*">
    #...options...
</Directory>
```